# how to add text instead of replacing them while using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I’m working on a project that uses tkinter and the buttons. So lets say my window has a text 'hi' and a button that displays 'bye' when I click it. When I click it 'hi' is replaced with 'bye', but I want to append 'bye'. How do I stop it from replacing my existing text?

This is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome ")
window.geometry('1000x200')
    
lbl = Label(window, text="Hi")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

def click():
    lbl.configure(text="bye")

btn = Button(window, text="click here", command=click)    
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
    
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cget` to get the content, then update it as you wish; for instance:

```
def click():
    lbl.configure(text=lbl.cget('text')+" bye")
```